# Visual Studio Code snippets removes the $ symbol from it

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Okay, so. I am making a snippet that has this in it:

`$title[Test]`, but, in order for the code to work `$` still needs to remain, but it actually gets removed for some reason from the output of the snippet. So I was wondering if it's a bug, or something I could bypass? I tried `\`, `/` and other stuff. None worked.

Comment: I meant to write "In order for the code to work, '$' still needs to be existent. And since the whole thing contains more stuff with $, it's very annoying and just doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to escape the dollar sign using two backslashes in your snippet JSON file.

```json
{
  "My snippet": {
    "prefix": "title-test",
    "body": ["\\$title[Test]"]
  }
}
```